# Looking for Yoshinkan Aikido Dojos in Osaka

Tags: aikido, dojo

I am living in Osaka right now and am interested in learning Yoshinkan Aikido. I could not find a dojo so I need your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is way too localised and could be answered by a simple Google search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: I also vtc, but "too localized" has not been a close reason for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This webpage](http://www.aikidoryu.or.jp/eng/dojo/index.html) lists several Yosinkan dojo's in Japan, but the link to the Osaka dojo leads to a [Japanse website with no translation](http://www.ryu-osaka.net/). However, if Google translate is any good, there are 3 places they train:

1. Beikomu gymnasium judo field, Amagasaki Nishinagasu cho 1-4-1
2. Budokan Hibiki, Toyonaka Hattorinishi cho 4-13-2
3. DaiSusumu building 5F, Chuo-ku, Osaka Kyutaro cho 3-3-5.

Comment: You are far nicer than I am...